# Realm -beginWriteTransaction killing the thread

Tags: objective-c, realm

My app downloads a lot of information from my backend and I also have to save these info locally. I've been using `Realm` to do so, but there's an annoying problem that I can't figure out why this is happening.

It doesn't happen all the time, but it does happen when I've downloaded many things and do one transaction after another. 
Some times when I call  `[realm beginWriteTransaction];` the realm raises an exception but I can't get it using a try / catch function, so I would like to know if you somebody has already gone through that.

It always happens when I'm doing something in background and I've always check if the realm is not in a write transaction before starting a new one

Thanks

Comment: This requires when you modify an object that was saved in the realm database , if you modify a property of the object that you have saved, you must use it `realm.write` or `realm.beginWriteTransaction`

Comment: You shouldn't begin write transaction inside a change listener / notification token

Comment: it is hard to tell, if there are any imbalances in opening and closing the realm transactions as you haven't mentioned code. You said you are checking before opening every open transaction, are you also checking before closing a connection, so that you dont perform mismatched open/close transactions. I would suggest only open a transaction before you download and close it after you download.

Comment: Regarding "im doing something on background",  when you first create the realm instance, make sure you use the realm in the same thread you create it, else it will crash. Realm isn't thread safe by defualt.

Comment: I haven't have any problem regarding starting a transaction in a different thread, I'm not getting an exception at all. I also don't get any problem when changing any property, what I'm basically doing is:

1) I make an API call, I get the information and save into the database
2) I make another API call to get another information and also save into the database
So I keep doing until I get all the information I need, the problem happens when I save a lot of information in the database and eventually, the `realm.beginWriteTransaction` kills the thread.

Comment: I think it could be somehow related to deadlock